# What is this vim custom map doing?

Tags: ruby, vim

It has something to do with running the a TestUnit file i.e. it switches out of vim and runs the file.

```
:map ,t :w\|:!ruby test_spec.rb<cr>
```

Can someone break this command out with some explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:w
```

saves the file

```
|
```

Let's you input multiple commands, e.g. `:foo|:bar`, is the same as `:foo`, hitting return, `:bar`. The `\` is to escape it in the map.

```
:!
```

Runs the shell command specified, in this case `ruby test_spec.rb`.

```
<CR>
```

Carriage return (e.g. the enter or return key).

So when you hit ,t, it saves your file, and runs the command `ruby test_spec.rb`.

Comment: so its a very specific map i.e. its locked to a particular file, it would be cool if it would run the file that is being viewed or where the cursor is.

Comment: @Blankman that's entirely possible, `%` will expand to the current file in the context of `:!somecommand %`